# How to access the IR sensor of MacBook Pro Mid 2010 to be able to use non apple remotes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ios

I have an Audio to IR accessory for my iPhone which works very well with most of the TVs and DVD players as the app that comes with it supports them.

I was wondering if it would be possible to write an iPhone App + Mac App that would let me control my MacBook Pro similar to how Apple remote works.

Is the IR sensor on MacBooks accessible to third party applications ?

Any Open Source Projects, SDK's or hacks you nice people can point me towards ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate candlair, or its big brother, Remote Buddy (google them). Candlair I believe only supports apple remotes, but remote buddy should let you configure other types of remotes with relative ease (they have a supported hardware list which is significantly larger than the stock IR port's driver). I've never used it though since my apple remote does everything i need. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the IR signals directly (read impulses). Third party applications can only capture remote "key presses". You could attach third party IR receiver.

Why don't you take the better way - pair your apps via the local network and use it for communication. If you insist on using IR - you're limited to the 7 keys on the remote.

ps. I have an idea - research the security code sent by the remote control. If you could capture it on a software level, you could have access to many "key codes" on your mac app.

Comment: I have already done that local network thing long time back with php exec using standard web sharing stuff. My main interest is in exploiting the IR sensor already there on the MacBook Pros combined with an iOS app.

Answer (score -1):

**Below is the original "content of my post":**

I use the Ignition app from LogMeIn on my iPhone/iPad via the network to fully control my Mac.

It works at home and I've also used it in an Iowa cornfield via a cellular data connection.

**I posted this in reply a few weeks ago in response to a different question regarding remote computer/screen control.**

**I have no idea why it linked to this question.**